# where is Paths.getDataFile in Haskell (reactive-banana)?

Tags: haskell, ghc, reactive-banana

I am testing reactive-banana 0.8.0.0 using one of the examples involving [animation](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Animation.hs)

I get an error about the `Paths` module not found. The problem line is:

```
import Paths (getDataFile)
```

and error is:

```
D:\temp\animation.hs:11:8:
    Could not find module `Paths'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude> :load "d:/temp/animation.hs"
```

Anyone know where to get or how to install this module?
(I am using Haskell Platform 2013.2 and mingw32 from mingw.org on Windows XP 64).

Comment: It's a module generated/provided by Cabal, which can be used to e.g. retrieve data files from an installed Cabal package. AFAIK, you can't just use it separately.

Comment: Thanks. So, should I make a cabal file for Animation.hs if I want to test it manually? Any special requirement for the cabal file?

Comment: @TingL Presumably there is already a cabal file included in the package. Type `cabal repl` and import the file and you should be good to go.

Comment: @TingL: No, use the cabal file provided in `reactive-banana-wx`. You can use `cabal repl`, as indicated by Daniel Wagner. Alternatively, you could set the `buildExamples` flag (`cabal configure -f buildExamples`) and build the package (`cabal build`), which will give you an executable called `Animation` somewhere in the `dist` directory.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I tried that and encountered a segfault in wxc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367950/wxc-segfault-in-wxhaskell. But it's a different issue.

Comment: @TingL Which did you try? repl or configure & build, or both?

Comment: I used -f buildExamples and redid cabal install. But every example I tried gave a segfault as I described in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be outdated by now but I just happened to end up at this page somehow. As of this writing, the module appears to be [included](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/565d190fddd17a7224dd3609852716b989bfa885/reactive-banana-wx/src/Paths.hs) in the package itself under the "src" directory.

This doesn't appear to be exposed in the [cabal file](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/565d190fddd17a7224dd3609852716b989bfa885/reactive-banana-wx/reactive-banana-wx.cabal) so it's not part of the package's public interface. Instead it is only listed under `other-modules` for the Animation executable.

```
Executable Animation
    if flag(buildExamples)
        build-depends:
            process >= 1.0 && < 1.4,
            random >= 1.0 && <= 1.1,
            executable-path == 0.0.*,
            filepath >= 1.1 && <= 1.4.0.0,
            reactive-banana, wx, wxcore, base
        cpp-options: -DbuildExamples
    else
        buildable: False
    hs-source-dirs:  src
    other-modules:   Paths_reactive_banana_wx, Paths
    main-is:         Animation.hs
```

To answer the question of "where to get or how to install this module" - just use the cabal file included in the package.